# Windows 7 boot issue after failed shut-down

Tags: windows-7, boot

After a failed shut-down (I turned the electricity off during the shut-down process), Windows is not able to start again.  The result of my mistake is that I always see a black screen. I'm still able to select one of the Windows boot options via <kbd>F8</kbd>.  But, it doesn't matter what I choose.  I always see the black screen in the end.  It seems like Windows is trying to start because I see the Windows logo and then it switches to the black screen. 
For troubleshooting I tried all of the boot options.  I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> when the screen goes black but without any effect. I already tried to recover the system with the Windows recovery tool, but I still have the same effect. I also started the system with boot logging options but I didn't find any log file (`c:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt`).

I have no idea what I should try next to recover my system. Does anyone know what I can do to correct this issue?

Comment: Did you try a startup repair?...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: This sounds a lot like the windows reboot loop, just without the reboot. Mine always crashed just as the windows logo started to fly onto the screen. By selecting the F8 option "disable automatic restart" I was able to see a blue screen of death, and this had a useful error code you could google.

Comment: @Moab: Yes, I did unfortunately it couldn't repair the system :(

Comment: From a command prompt (booted from a W7 disc) run this command, it will run for some time, when it is done reboot, see if windows will load, if not try another startup repair...sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\  /offwindir=d:\windows.... your drive letter may not be D:... http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/139810-sfc-scannow-run-command-prompt-boot.html